# Swift: Initialize objects from string

Tags: swift, object, struct

I defined a struct in my model, similar to

```
struct MyObject {
    var ID: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Now in code I would create objects like the following:

```
let newObj = MyObject(ID: 3, name: "AAAA")
```

I need to create some objects on runtime now based on a string input. I.e. I would like to provide a string like `'MyObject(ID: 3, name: "AAAA")'` and create an object from it. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: That sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Sweeper I have a UITextView and I would like to provide a string with objects to create, and after a button tap the ViewController should create all the provided objects. It is a functionality in a Debugger View to debug objects.

Comment: Swift programs don't include an interpreter for Swift code.  You'd have to build it yourself.

Comment: Why not something simple like "id:3,name:AAAA"